# Buttons overlap each other

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the following code:

```
    self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, _("a"))
    self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, _("b"))
    btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    btnSizer.Add(self.btn1 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
    btnSizer.Add(self.btn2 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
```

This works well.
However there is a case where I change the title of `btn2` :

```
self.btn1.SetLabel('bbbbb')
```

When I do that `btn1` overlaps `btn2`....

first row is the original 
second row is after set label.

[image]

How do I make the screen refresh to the new size of buttons?

Comment: Your code is not enough to test this. Do you have nested sizers or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `self.Layout()` but in this case it really shouldn't be necessary. There must be some issue that you are having with your code.

```
import wx

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, value):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("a"))
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, ("b"))
        self.btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btn1 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btnSizer.Add(self.btn2 , 0, wx.RIGHT, 10)
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPressA)
        self.btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPressB)
        self.SetSizer(self.btnSizer)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

    def OnPressA(self,evt):
        self.btn1.SetLabel('bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb')
#        self.Layout()

    def OnPressB(self,evt):
        self.btn2.SetLabel('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
#        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    ButtonFrame(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: `Update()` just triggers a repaint of the widget.  What is needed in this case is something like `self.btnSizer.Layout()`

Comment: @RobinDunn Thanks, adjusted accordingly. Although, I still think there is some other issue that the OP has with their code.